# How can I fix jquery noConflict, with aboveHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, sticky

This jQuery code is working well, but I want to implement a fixed point, I want to replace the 510 with a relative point, from css: #content

```
var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();
            _rys("document").ready(function () {
                _rys(window).scroll(function () {
                    if (_rys(this).scrollTop() > 510) {
                        _rys('.navigation').addClass("fixed");
                    } else {
                        _rys('.navigation').removeClass("fixed");
                    }
                });
            });
```

I converted this code, but its not working, and I did not realize why :) 
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var aboveHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
              $('.navigation').addClass("fixed");
                    }
        else {
              $('.navigation').removeClass("fixed");
                    }
        });
    });
```

The working version: thanks Dinesh Kumar DJ

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var aboveHeight = jQuery('#content').offset().top;
            console.log(jQuery('#content'));
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
      jQuery('.navigation').addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      jQuery('.navigation').removeClass("fixed");
    }
});   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all $ by jQuery, it will work fine,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var aboveHeight = jQuery('header').outerHeight();
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
          jQuery('.navigation').addClass("fixed");
        } else {
          jQuery('.navigation').removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well done, it works fine, but I have a little problem with this, when I add this: $('#content').outerHeight(); it doesn't do it correctly... and thank you very much

Comment: you have to pass true as an argument like jQuery('#content').outerHeight(true); to add margin also to get correct height.

Comment: I created from my original page an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hmb4U/ do not want to work correctly ...i no way I want to sticky after the Lorem, but is shows after the end of Lorem

Comment: i have updated the jsFiddle, you have to specify the top of any element from where you want to make the menu fixed

Comment: for me its not working jsFiddle, but what do you mean to specify the top of element ?

Comment: for me is all the same using whichever class or ID what is before the article, the point would be to sticky the menu after you scroll down and you cant see the menu ...

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Hmb4U/2 its working-the best, what I want, but on the real site do not want to work correctly ...

Comment: what is your requirement then, is it okay.

Comment: I do not understand why can work on jsFiddle and why not in real, its a jquery conflict?

Comment: When I disabled the slider it works, but when I enable its not working... its possible to do not count the slideshow size?

Comment: change document.ready function to window.load, like jQuery(document).ready(function(){ //code }); to jQuery(window).load(function(){  //code });, since the top is calculated 140 before the slider loads, or try to calculate the offset top after slider loads, it will work perfectly

Comment: thank you very much for your help and your time for me :) I am very thankful for this

Comment: Can you help me a litlle bit ?

Comment: on the webpage http://www.szit-ifi.ro/ there are 2 jquery code, but I got
Empty string passed to getElementById() and its not working correct ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A5hDm/    with this 2 code I want to achieve that, when the screen size is under 460  px and you scroll down to show a toggle-fixed menu, not a simple fixed menu

Comment: the scroll function will be called only when the user releases the touch from the mobile device, please state the exact requirement

Comment: a resolved this, thanks :) now its fully responsive, has a mobile menu and a fixed menu when is not scrolled ...